# Showing that if $|a_n|<|b_n|$ and $\sum b_k x^k$ converges, then $\sum a_k x^k$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Hypothesis: $|a_{n}|<|b_{n}|$ for all natural $n$, and  $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_{k}x^k$ converges on $(-R, R)$. Prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} x^k$ converges on $(-R, R)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: It looks like you need to do a *comparison* here.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast. I have tried to use the comparison test for series, but failed. $ -|b_{n}|<=a_{n}<=|b_{n}| $. I've also tried in another way, to use that for non-zero terms we have $ \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}<b<1 $ for fixed b independent of n, but the terms of the series $ a_{n} $ are not only positive or only negative. Had them been so I could have used the monotonic sequence theorem to prove it.

Comment: EDIT: And $ \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}>c>-1 $ for fixed independent c.

Comment: LATER EDIT : Ahh!! I think I got it. For positive $ b_{n} $ I have $ a_{n}<bb_{n} $ , and for negative I have $ a_{n}<cb_{n}<bb_{n} $. Is that correct?

Comment: Oh wait! For negative $ b_{n} $ we have $ cb_{n}>bb_{n} $.

Comment: Thanks TMM for editing it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $x \in (-R, R)$. Then there exists $r$ such that $|x| < r < R$. Since

$$ \sum_{n=}^{\infty} b_n r^n $$

converges, $b_n r^n$ is bounded by some constant, say $M > 0$. Then

$$\left| a_n x^n \right| \leq |b_n| |x|^n = |b_n|r^n \left( \frac{|x|}{r} \right)^n \leq M \left( \frac{|x|}{r} \right)^n. $$

Thus by comparison test, it follows that $\sum a_n x^n$ converges absolutely. Since this is true for any $x \in (-R, R)$, $\sum a_n x^n$ converges on $(-R, R)$.

Comment: Ok, thanks but more important could you take a look up to what I wrote and see whether that is correct or not? Why is $ |b_{n}|r^n<=M $ ?

Comment: Nvm, figured out.